# Form submitting multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have been using jQuery 1.8.3, and have two forms and two radio buttons, form will show when click on the radio buttons. what i am doing here is when click on save button, i will check which radio is checked, depends on that form will submit, the problem is after one form submit, that request going as ajax, so i am not refresh the page after one submit, when click on the save button, **two times** the form will submit, and next time **4 times**...?

**js code**

```
$(".save").live("click", function() {
  if ($("#b1").is(":checked")) {
    $("#lForm1").submit();
  }
  if ($("#b2").is(":checked")) {
    $("#lForm2").submit();
  }
});

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  //here toggle the form
});
```

**html**

```
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="b1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="b2" >
<%= form_tag '/contact/create_check', method: :post, remote: true, id: 
'lForm1' %>
<%= form_tag '/contact/create_count', method: :post, remote: true, id: 
'lForm2' %>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success save" value="Save" />
```

Comment: Are there any multiple forms?

Comment: yes @Kuldeep, have two forms, but only submit one form at a time

Comment: can you please post complete html.

Answer (score 0):

Please do something like this instead

```
$(function() {
  $("#lForm1").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    if ($("#b1").is(":checked")) {
      $.ajax({url:$("#lform1").prop("action"),data:$("#lform1").serialize()});
    }
    else if ($("#b2").is(":checked")) {
      $.ajax({url:$("#lform2").prop("action"),data:$("#lform2").serialize()});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but this gives error like Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: "Something like" - you have not posted enough info for my suggestion to be taken verbatim- just study the parts like preventDefault and the use of on submit, assuming you have a submit button - otherwise use the on click of the radios

Comment: I added a missing `url` and some curly brackets